# false as Bool return nil instead of Optional(false)

Tags: swift

Recently joined a new project and noticed, in project expression `false as Bool?` returns `nil` instead of `Optional(false)`.

XCode 14.1, 14.2. Same expression in playground returns Optional(false). All swift compiler optimizations are disabled. What could case this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Ideally the type cast should work, I wonder why the type cast needed can you share more code? Ex: `var value: Bool? = false` then can be assigned with true or nil directly without type cast.

Comment: I'm trying to show the problem as abstracted as possible from our entities. The problem is reproduced on basic types and I want to find out what causes such incorrect type casting
 

`var value: Bool? = false // nil`

Comment: Please share the code that generates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone redefined `init(booleanLiteral:)` in the project.

```swift
extension Bool?: ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral {
  public init(booleanLiteral bool: Wrapped) {
    self = bool ? bool : nil
  }
}
```